# Get array from hash with arrays as values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, enumerable

Given the following Hash `hash` with keys as symbols and values as arrays:

```
hash
#=> {:stage_item=>[:stage_batch_id, :potential_item_id], :item=>[:id, :size, :color, :status, :price_sold, :sold_at], :style=>[:wholesale_price, :retail_price, :type, :name]}
```

How do I get an array with of just the values (arrays) added together?

I know I can use [`#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [`#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
hash.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), array| array << v }.flatten
#=> [:stage_batch_id, :potential_item_id, :id, :size, :color, :status, :price_sold, :sold_at, :wholesale_price, :retail_price, :type, :name]
```

But I was expecting just `#each_with_object` to work:

```
hash.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), array| array += v }
#=> []
```

I though the point of each with object is it keeps track of the accumulator (named `array` in this case), so I can `+=` it like in the following example:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
arr += [4]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array << ..` changes the original array in-place:

```
irb(main):014:0> a = original = []
=> []
irb(main):015:0> a << [1]
=> [[1]]
irb(main):016:0> a
=> [[1]]
irb(main):017:0> original
=> [[1]]
irb(main):018:0> a.equal? original  # identity check
=> true
```

while, `Array += ..` returns a new array without changing the original array:

```
irb(main):019:0 a = original = []
=> []
irb(main):020:0> a += [1]
=> [1]
irb(main):021:0> a
=> [1]
irb(main):022:0> original
=> []
irb(main):023:0> a.equal? original
=> false
```

According to [`Enumerable#each_with_object` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object),

> Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object
>   given, and **returns the initially given object.**
>
> If no block is given, returns an enumerator.

so, in case of `+=`, returns the initial empty array which is not modified.

---

BTW, instead of using `each_with_object`, you can simply use [`Hash#values` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) which returns a new array populated with the values from the hash:

```
hash.values.flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a case where `inject` would be a better fit if you insist on using `Array#+`:

```
hash.inject([]) { |a, (_, v)| a + v }
```

The reason you generally use `each_with_object` rather than `inject` is if you want to accumulate results in-place rather than using the block's return value as the accumulator. In this case `array1 + array2` returns the concatenation so you don't need to use an operator (or method) that modifies the memo object because `Array#+` returns what you want to feed into the next cycle.

While we're here, these would be simpler:

```
hash.values.flatten
hash.values.inject(:+)
h.values.flat_map(&:itself)
```

and the second even uses `Array#+` if you really like calling that method.